# Modify JQuery UI tabs to tab through the tabs

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

How can I modify the JQuery UI tabs so that my users can go through them using tab and shift/tab, just like they can the rest of the page?  Rather than needing to use the arrow keys.

I'm using jQuery UI v1.10.3

This is the code I have, it's basically the example on their site:

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>jQuery UI Tabs - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs({
        event: "click"
    });
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">Tab 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2">Tab 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-3">Tab 3</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="tabs-1">
    <p>Tab 1</p>
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-2">
    <p>Tab 2</p>
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-3">
    <p>Tab 3</p>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

I need to modify it so users can tab to select a tab, rather than using the arrow keys.  I can almost get there by adding:

```
$('ul.ui-tabs-nav>li,ul.ui-tabs-nav>li>a').removeAttr("tabindex");
```

But I don't know if that's the best solution and I need that to run everytime a tab is selected, not just on page load.

Comment: Can you show what you have done so far?

Comment: I haven't modified anything.  The example on their site is accurate: http://jqueryui.com/tabs/

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results.

Comment: ok, my issue is the tabindex="-1" that's being placed on the links.  I cannot figure out how to stop that from happening.  I'll put together an example and add it to my question.  thanks.

Comment: A good start would be to have a look at the tabs widget source code itself. If the arrow keys are already supported, it must come from somewhere right ? Quick hint: look at the method `_tabKeydown`. Let yourself get inspired ;-)

Comment: I don't need to remove the arrow key functionality.  I just need to remove the tabindex="-1".  Is there an event I can attach to that will fire everytime a tab is selected?